# Django: Ordering by last item in reverse ForeignKey relation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to implement a `qs.sort_by` operation, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Given the following models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ( ... )


class Budget(models.Model):
    ( ... )
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=8,
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        related_name="budgets",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Where each `Group` has either `0` or `> 5` budgets assigned

I am trying to sort a `Group.objects.all()` queryset by the amount of their `last` (as in, most recently assigned) `Budget`.

I know that if it was a `OneToOne` I could do something like the following:

```
Group.objects.all().order_by('budget__amount')
```

With `ForeignKey` relations I was hoping I could do something like

```
Group.objects.all().order_by('budgets__last__amount')
```

But alas, that is not a valid operation, but I am not sure on how to proceed otherwise.

Does anyone know on how to perform this sorting operation? (if it is indeed possible)

Comment: You'll have to use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), but I don't have time right now to just type out the exact answer for you. Something along the lines of `Group.objects.annotate(last_amount=Min('budget__amount').order_by('last_amount')`.

Comment: What determines what is last? Do you have a timestamp field on Budget?

Comment: At this moment I 'm using the default primary key value. All queries use the Group.budgets.last() logic

Comment: @Jasper Do you have a way to manually get each `budgets__last__amount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
latest = Budget.objects.filter(group=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-pk')

Group.objects.annotate(
    latest_budget=Subquery(
        latest.values('amount')[:1]
    )
).order_by('latest_budget')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `sorted` with a custom key:

```
sorted(Group.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.last__budget__amount)
```

Perhaps `.last__budget__amount` is not a valid method, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Alas, this results in the `object has no attribute 'last__budget__amount'`. Using `last__` does not seem to be a valid method in this context.

Comment: @Jasper I know. Whatever is the manual method to get each last budget amount, you can apply that to the `x`.

Comment: Don't do in python what you can do in the database.